# How to remove some string with awk/sed or another command in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I want to ask, how I can remove some string with command in linux?

```
cat /data/filename.txt 
A|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|0030|12|05/09/17 
B|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|00045|12|05/09/17
C|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|061|12|05/09/17
```

and the output:

```
cat /data/filename.txt 
A|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|30|12|05/09/17
B|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|45|12|05/09/17
C|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|61|12|05/09/17
```

Comment: Not clear enough. You want to remove all leading 0s in any column or just the 2nd last column or just the 10th column (assuming 0 based) or just leading zeros in front of "11" (in any column) ?

Comment: just the 10th column sir and all in front of in that column.
another example :
    2014|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|0019|12 and become 2014|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|19|12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
awk -F"|" '{sub(/^0+/,"",$11)} 1' OFS="|"   Input_file
```

Making field separator as | then substituting the starting zeros with NULL of 111th field as per your requirements, mentioning 1 will print the newly edited line(if any zeros were replaced with NULL), setting Output field separator as | and mentioning the Input_file then.

**EDIT:** Adding 2nd solution for removing -000 into 11th field as follows.

```
awk -F"|" '{sub(/^0+/,"",$11);sub(/-0+/,"-",$11)} 1' OFS="|" Input_file
```

Here I am making | as field separator then substituting the starting zeros in 11th field with NULL and then substituting the -0+ means from -0 till all the zeros to NULL too here and then 1 will print the lines. Setting Output field separator as | too.

Comment: hai @ravinder, can i ask u again ? 
it turns out, i need a little favor from u,,if the format into this A|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|0030-00456|12|05/09/17 so i need like this A|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|30-456|12|05/09/17 do u have idea how transform into like that?

Comment: @wirawiri: Please see my edited answer now, let me know if this helps you.

Comment: yaps...it also worked sir..thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Another option with awk:

```
awk -F\| -vOFS=\| '{$11+=0}1' file
```

Comment: Please tell us what is going on!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=sprintf("%d", $i)}1' /data/filename.txt

2014|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12
2015|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12
2016|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12
```

**Assumption**: Your file contains only integer values delimited by `|`

Comment: oh my bad, there is some character are in string values :( ,, and that string will become 0 values right ?
i'll fix my question to avoid that